# Receiving "connection with batcomputer jammed" when trying to disarm jammer

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I am in the Communications Tower of the Diamond District, and when I try to disable the jammer I get the following message:

> connection with batcomputer jammed

Can I do something about this, or should I wait for when I have more gadgets later on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a gadget that you will receive later on which allows you to disable the various jamming devices you may encounter. You can't miss it in the story playthrough, so you can just wait for that.

**If you don't mind spoilers**, here's exactly where to find it:

> You get this when headed into Gotham Police Department, in the evidence locker.

Comment: Spoilers are >!.

Comment: Thanks, it would be nice if Batman said something like "I think I should get back later on" to give a clue. Because this game has a few bugs, I am often wondering if this is a bug or intended.

Comment: Yup. The game really didn't feel polished to me. There were many times it crashed on me and many things that weren't explained at all and I only knew from previous batman games (nowhere in the game for example does it tell you about scanning things in detective mode that I recall and I certainly didn't realise that the plaques around the place could be). :(

Answer (score 1):

It seems that there is a window which is boarded up and which can be destroyed to access the jammer but you need to have gadgets which can be obtained later depending of where you are in the game.

Once you are there, you can disable the jammer with the appropriate gadget.

Comment: You don't need the shock gloves to do so. You can break through boarded up windows by flying through them. Also I don't think you have actually answered the question really... :)

Comment: True, I was only repeating what somebody told me on Steam but I corrected my answer (I finished the game since then)

Comment: @Chris you can break through **some** boards by flying through them, but not all of them. The Riddler tower that requires shock gloves to beat has boards that can only be broken with explosive gel, for example.

Comment: @kotekzot: I have flown through these specific ones. It was a tricky feet to line it up properly (if you are too far off centre he just does the wall jump thing) but I did do that. This was annoyingly before I had the appropriate gadget though. :)

Comment: @Chris huh, well done, I assumed they were unbreakable after the 3rd attempt or so.